# Starting a Fragment Inside ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I have a gridview that gets populated with ArrayAdapter. Within the GridView I have a Button and ImageView. I made a Listener for the Button and Image however I would like to start a Fragment once I tap on the ImageView. And I got the Error in using getSupportFragmentManager();.

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

This is my code for my ArrayAdapter Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
    Context context;
    int imgId;



public MyAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items){
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}


private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    Button btn;
    TextView textView;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)        context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPocket);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    Picasso.with(context)
            //.load("http://www.balay-indang.com/megamobile/pics/"+   String.valueOf(position+1) +".png")
            .load(rowItem.getImgUrl())
            .resize(200,150)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.textView.setText(rowItem.getText());
    holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(rowItem.getPocketId());

    final String pos = String.valueOf(position);

    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pocket: "+ pos,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: what error your are getting?

Comment: cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: Are you extending FragmentActivity() from your Activity?? I would check your imports and make sure you have android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager instead of android.app.FragmentManager imported

Comment: @GmloMalo I'am only extending Fragment for both the current and about to call Fragment.

Comment: So you are calling your detailedFragment from another fragment? In this case you only can call getSupportFragment Manager from an Activity extending FragmentActivity because the method is only supported for that? Have you checked your imports?

Comment: @GmloMalo yes. I have checked and tried both possible imports.

Comment: Then you can use getsupportFragmentManager inside a Fragment. Is only defined for FragmentActivity.

Comment: The snippet provied is from my arrayadapter. That's why I'm having trouble starting a fragment from an onclicklistener inside an arrayadapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only access getSupportedFragmentManager from an FragmentActivity class.
If you have to access getSupportedFragmentManager in your adapter then you have pass activity's instance through constructor.

getSupportFragmentManager() is only defined for the class FragmentActivity.

**EDIT:**

If your MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity then try this.

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((ActionBarActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wait so you are saying that I'am supposed to extend my Fragment to FragmentActivity? And Replace my ArrayAdapter's default constructor with your first snippet?

Comment: See edited answer. your main activity extending ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity or something else?

Comment: I have provided my Full code for my adapter. Can you explain to me further what I need to change? I already removed the super() method however it still returns an error. "There is no default constructor available".

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((ActionBarActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(); is getting an error: incompatible types.  required android.app.FragmentManager. Found android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager. Sorry I forgot to mention I'am extending AppCompatActivity in my MainActivity

Comment: try getFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Now I have one last error. fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

it says replace (int, android.app.fragment) to (int, detailsfragment);

Comment: Sorry I figured it out already. I changed my DetailsFragment import to android.app.fragment. Is there a work around I can do if I want to use the other import. Which is android.support.v4.app.Fragment; ??

Comment: yes you have to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Is your current activity a "Fragment" activity?

Comment: Yes, the gridview is within the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity needs to extend and Activity that inherits from **FragmentActivity** in order to have getSupportFragmentManager() and other support methods available.

At the time of my answer your activity should extend **AppCompatActivity**. Also ensure that relevant imports use the support classes such as

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```